# java servlet while loop cut short with mysql INSERT INTO

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, selenium-webdriver

i am making a java servlet with selenium that loops a certain number of times and inserts into a db. but The loop stops after 1 INSERT.

```
while(i < x)
        {

            i++;
            if(rs.next())
            {                       
                String st = rs.getString("st");
                String ACCOUNT = rs.getString("User");
                String link_URL = rs.getString("Link");
                String objectKey = rs.getString("Key");
                String DESC = "File description.";
                String INF_DESC = " this is an unsual from";                

                WebElement acc = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("web_account_"+i)));
                WebElement desc = driver.findElement(By.id("web_original_"+i));
                WebElement inf_desc = driver.findElement(By.id("web_se_"+i));
                WebElement _url = driver.findElement(By.id("web_url_"+i));
                List<WebElement> link_in_ = driver.findElements(By.name("web_target_"+i));
                WebElement link_in__1 = driver.findElement(By.id("web_website_direct_"+i));
                WebElement link_in__conf = driver.findElement(By.id("web_website_direct_confirm_"+i));
                WebElement report_another = driver.findElement(By.id("more_link"));

                acc.sendKeys(ACCOUNT);
                top("Account: ", ACCOUNT, complete, response, 1);

                desc.sendKeys(DESC);
                top("Description: ", DESC, complete, response, 1);

                inf_desc.sendKeys(INF_DESC);
                top("Inf_Des: ", INF_DESC, complete, response, 1);

                _url.sendKeys(link_URL);
                top("URL: ", link_URL, complete, response, 1);

                for(WebElement RadioOption : link_in_)
                {
                    //if(RadioOption.getAttribute("value").equals("website"))
                    if("website".equals(RadioOption.getAttribute("value")))
                    RadioOption.click();
                    top("Radio in URL: ", clicked, complete, response, 1);                                                                  
                }


                link_in_1.click();
                top("Radio in URL2: ", clicked, complete, response, 1);


                link_in_conf.click();
                top("Radio URL3 Conf: ", clicked, complete, response, 1);

                //store current webs in a temp table
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp_webs (ObjectKey) VALUES ('" + objectKey + "')");

                if(i != x)
                {
                        report_another.click();
                        writer.println("<tr><td>Report Another:</td><td colspan=\"2\">Click</td><td>Complete</td></tr>");

                }

            }
            else
            {
                writer.println("There was an error in the MySQL query! ID:26");
            }


        }
```

I know the issue is that the `st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp_webs (ObjectKey) VALUES ('" + objectKey + "')");` is preventing the loop from continuing. When I remove this line of code it works perfectly fine.

**UPDATE**
I have confirmed that the query works and everything is correct. My problem is it only inserts one record and then it exits the while loop.

**UPDATE TWO**
I got a new error after using the query in a try catch
`Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`
it seems that the ResulSet closing before completing the loop. Not sure what would cause this.

Comment: Any error occurred? About `st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp_webs (ObjectKey) VALUES ('" + Key + "')");`, are you sure that the column in your table is called `ObjectKey` and what the variable `Key` contains?

Comment: What is the value of `Key`? Some SQL injection going on here.

Comment: yes, I'm 100% the query is correct. I test in mysql and as well as the servlet. But the combination of everything causes the loop to stop. The key is a Primary key from the db that is put into a temp table. it looks like this `a11623a5f98ede8da726a6cda6f1f408543f3da`

Comment: any ideas? I've hit a brick wall here. No matter what I do I cant get the query to complete the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to create a new statement connection and use the new one inside the loop. The reason it was stopping was because the connection was being closed after the first loop.